# PHP - How to add more than 2 parameters to a variable?

Tags: php, function, random, warnings

So I have the following code:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>
<?php
$var = rand(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
if ($var == 1){
print '<a href="/dir1/file1">link1</a>';
}
if ($var == 2){
print '<a href="/dir2/file2">link2</a>';
}
if ($var == 3){
print '<a href="/dir3/file3">link3</a>';
}
if ($var == 4){
print '<a href="/dir4/file4">link4</a>';
}
if ($var == 5){
print '<a href="/dir5/file5">link5</a>';
}
if ($var == 6){
print '<a href="/dir6/file6">link6</a>';
}
if ($var == 7){
print '<a href="/dir7/file7">link7</a>';
}
if ($var == 8){
print '<a href="/dir8/file8">link8</a>';
}
if ($var == 9){
print '<a href="/dir9/file9">link9</a>';
}
if ($var == 10){
print '<a href="/dir10/file10">link10</a>';
}
?>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

But it outputs this error:

> "**Warning**:  rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 10 given..."

So I wonder how could I random the `values` of this `variable` and then `print()` only on in the `p` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your numbers are in sequence, you could simply do

```
$var = rand(1,10);   // that will work on range 1 - 10
```

**Function Prototype:**

> int rand ( int $min , int $max )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with how many arguments you can pass to a function, but what arguments that function expects.

`rand` takes 2 arguments - a minimum value and a maximum value. It doesn't take an unspecified number of arguments that it picks from.

You just want:

```
rand(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a condition here...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>
          <?php printf('<a href="/dir%d/file%d">link%d</a>', rand(1,10)); ?>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

will do..

will do..

The mistake you were doing is.. `rand()` expects two parameters.. the minimum number and the maximum number.

**Sidenote** : If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and getrandmax()

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = rand(1,10);
```

it means rand from 1 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Rand a number between low limit and upper limit `rand(0,10)`. If you have a list of numbers like 
`[1,14,1663,1773]` and you want to get a random number from these one, use the random function to get a number between 0 and count(array) - and than print the element at that index.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message is clear.

rand() function expects exactly two parameters.

If you want to generate a random number between 1 and 10, write this:

`rand('1', '10')`